# Extra information for each word in richtextbox- Link between richtextbox and sql table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c#-4.0, controls

I have a richtextbox that its text is a concatenation of some words from specific table. (table columns are 'word','translate' and 'id')

I need that when a user hover on each word, the related translate is showed in word's tooltip.
(something like google translate but in windows form application.)

Can somebody point me towards a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Web-browser Control and Injecting JavaScript solved my problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick...

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     // whitespace definition
     char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t' };

     int charPosition = this.richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);

     string fullText = this.richTextBox1.Text;

     // if we are on whitespace, exit
     if (whitespace.Contains(fullText[charPosition]))
     {
         return;
     }

     // find a whitespace towards the start of the text
     int firstWhiteSpace = charPosition;
     while (firstWhiteSpace > 0
         && firstWhiteSpace < fullText.Length
         && !whitespace.Contains(fullText[firstWhiteSpace]))
     {
         firstWhiteSpace--;
     }
     if (firstWhiteSpace!=0)
         firstWhiteSpace++;
     // find the next whitespace
     int lastWhiteSpace = fullText.IndexOfAny(whitespace, charPosition);
     if (lastWhiteSpace == -1)
         lastWhiteSpace = fullText.Length;

     // substring the word out of the flat text
     string word = fullText.Substring(
         firstWhiteSpace, 
         lastWhiteSpace - firstWhiteSpace);

     // show the result
     label1.Text = String.Format("pos:{0} fsp:{1}, lsp:{2}, len:{3}, word:{4}", 
         charPosition, 
         firstWhiteSpace, 
         lastWhiteSpace, 
         fullText.Length, word);

 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. this is get the word. but, how can we have the relative id and translation?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not fluent in C#, and I am also brand new to this forum. However, it looks to me like if you were to supplement the code rene posted with a function which queries your Translation table and returns the translation text, you would then have this (forgive my pseudo-code butchery - I am very fluent in vb.net, gonna learn the C# syntax soon):

```
Private String TranslatedWord(ByVal SelectedWord String)
    {
        //Use ADO and SQL to retrieve the Translation(s) associated with the submitted Word

        // A string SQL Statement (the GROUP ON is in case there are multiple instances of the same word, with different translations (synonyms). THis SQL Should return a a single record for each possible translation of the submitted word (more than one result possible):
            Dim SQL as String = _
            "SELECT tr.ID, tr.Translate " & _
            "FROM MyTranslationTable AS tr " & _
            "WHERE tr.Word LIKE @Word"

        //Since I could be ALL DAY struggling to write the C# code for this, I will just step through it in "pseudocode": 
        // 1. Execute the SQL using ADO.Net, set up the @Word Param in your command, and return a sqlDataReader
        // 2. Iterate through the returned records, and append the Translation results to a System.Text.Stringbuilder object. Delimit each returned value with a semi-colon (or your delimiter of choice). 
        // Return the Stringbuilder.ToString property as the result of this function;
```

}

Then change the last part of rene's code ("//Show the result") as follows (suitable corrected for my horrible C# problem!):

```
        private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)                                        
    {                                             
        // whitespace definition                                             
        char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t' };                                                                                     
        int charPosition = this.richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);                                                                                     
        string fullText = this.richTextBox1.Text;

        // if we are on whitespace, exit                                             
        if (whitespace.Contains(fullText[charPosition]))                                             
        {                                                 
            return;                                             
        }                                                                                     
        // find a whitespace towards the start of the text                                             
        int firstWhiteSpace = charPosition;                                             
        while (firstWhiteSpace > 0                                                 
            && firstWhiteSpace < fullText.Length                                                 
            && !whitespace.Contains(fullText[firstWhiteSpace]))                                             
            {                                                 
            firstWhiteSpace--;                                             
        }                                             
        if (firstWhiteSpace!=0)                                                 
            firstWhiteSpace++;

        // find the next whitespace                                             
        int lastWhiteSpace = fullText.IndexOfAny(whitespace, charPosition);                                             
        if (lastWhiteSpace == -1)                                                 
            lastWhiteSpace = fullText.Length;

        // substring the word out of the flat text                                             
        string word = fullText.Substring(                                                 
            firstWhiteSpace,                                                  
            lastWhiteSpace - firstWhiteSpace);  

        // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
        //My CHanges start here, and will likely require 
        // some tweaking . . .

        //Use the function I have poorly described above to retreive the 
        //translation(s) for the current Word:
        string TRANSLATION = TranslatedWord(word);                                                         

        // show the result     
        //Since there are so many minor but important differences between C# and VB, I am not going to attempt
        //to account for them. Essentially, display the translated word instead of the word over which the mouse is hovering:                
        label1.Text = String.Format("pos:{0} fsp:{1}, lsp:{2}, len:{3}, word:{4}",                                                  
            charPosition,                                                  
            firstWhiteSpace,                                                  
            lastWhiteSpace,                                                  
            fullText.Length, TRANSLATION);      

    }
```

If it would be helpful, I could bust out the vb.net code for this fairly quickly, but I wasn't going to do that unless it would be helpful.

Hope that's helpful. I am going to have to work a little at learning C#, and at improving my understanding of posting in this forum! Getting the code to look right is proving a challenge . . .

Comment: thanks for your response. but,the big problem is "... WHERE tr.Word LIKE @Word". because in my application one word may have multiple translation base on its context. then we must exactly point to the corresponding translation id.

Comment: My thought was that if there were multiple translations dependent upon context, you would concatenate them ALL into the string you display as the tool Tip: e.g. Selected Word = Den, then Tool Tip Text = "Library; Nest; Hideaway" all synonyms for Den (off the top of my head). That concatenated string is what would be returned by the Function TranslatedWord(Word). THis would be relatively easy to code. Also, How would you do as you suggest, if the translation may be different depennding on context? How would the method described above know which context to use, in order to fetch the proper ID?

Comment: Forgot the translation and suppose that I need to show some extra information about each word at the tool-tip like Id,part of speech of the word or something else.